# Can't get asset pipeline working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, asset-pipeline

I can't get the asset pipeline working for some reason.  I get a 404 on request to both application.css and application.js.  I'm using rails 3.1.0.rc6.  Nothing special, just created a new project.

In my layout file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

It's linking to /stylesheets/application.css and same with the js file.  I'm using pow but also tried starting the server with webrick.

Any ideas?

Note: using sprockets 2.0.0.beta.15

Comment: I've also noticed that I'm missing the rake tasks for assets.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  I had to make an explicit require call to "sprockets/railtie"

Answer (score 2):

You might find that adding

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

to your config/environments/xxx.rb will help.

Answer (score 2):

To be more exact, add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'sprockets/railtie'
```